# Meeting of new people

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Consider that you have $p$ people and $t$ tables, where $p = t^2$. Each table has $t$ seats.

The meeting will have $t+1$ rounds. In each round, people will be seated to tables, each time meeting different people, so in the end, they will meet everyone exactly once.

After some time, I've found out, that it is a "social golfer problem". 
Is there some algorithm to find out quick general solution to this problem (at least for every "small" $t$)?

Comment: On each round a person will meet $t-1$ people, you will need $t+1$ rounds for them to meet the other $t^2-1$ people ?

Comment: Ehm... Yeah, of course.

Comment: Is the goal that everyone should meet everyone else as fast as possible in total?

Comment: @mathreadler I think the idea is that all $t^2$ people sit at the $t$ tables ... then they all move around & sit at a table with other people ... after $t+1$ rounds, everyone has sat at a table with everyone else exactly once.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Yep, that's it. Everyone can shuffle and find new table with new people. But the final goal is to find an optimal solution algorithm. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is equivalent to constructing an affine plane of order $t$, see [Wikiedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_plane_(incidence_geometry)) for more info. The people are the points, the parallel classes of lines are the rounds, and the lines within the parallel class are the table assignments in each round.

For a prime $t$, let the people be ordered pairs $(x,y)$ from $\{0 \ldots t-1\}$. Then one round, $(a,b)$ is at the same table as $(c,d)$ if and only if $a=c$. The remaining rounds are labelled by the numbers $m \in \{0 \ldots t-1\}$, and in round $m$, $(a,b)$ is at the same table as $(c,d)$ if and only if $b-am = d-cm$.

A similar construction works for $t$ a prime power using finite fields. No affine plane of non-prime power order is known, though non-existence is only proved for $t=6$ and $t=10$, plus those values excluded by the Bruck-Ryser-Chowla Theorem.